# Copying data from a table to archival tables based on column value MySQL

Tags: mysql, copy

I have a large MySQL table from which I want to copy data to 10 MyISAM archival tables based on a value of col (1 to 10). What is the most efficient way to do that? I guess simple `INSERT into arch1 (col1, col2, col3) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab WHERE col1=1` is too slow

Comment: I guess inserting into `MyISAM` table won't be slow. Have you tried?

Comment: Try it and let us know.

Comment: if col1 is indexed, you can't get faster, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this approach is good enough, thanks for the 3 notes